# How to combine account credits for Azure servers

Tags: azure, bizspark

I have a Microsoft BizSpark, but I need to create a D2 server (preferably two) on Azure, I would need more than $150, ($400 for two D2 servers). Since I can add up to four developers, is there a way to combine that credit so I can use it to create my servers?

**UPDATE** - I've submitted an Azure support request and the answer is the same as below, also https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing/suggestions/11162505-allow-pooling-of-azure-credits-for-bizspark-subscr

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a service/subscription topic, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170030-signup-and-billing/suggestions/5777168-allow-pooling-for-azure-credits-within-a-company

Unfortunately, Microsoft doesn't allow credit pooling from multiple subscriptions. You'll have to keep individual charges like the D2 server below the $150 limit, as it can only be charged to a single account at a time.

Comment: I see a lot more people having the same issue... I'm also waiting for official response from Azure support.